# Query on SoC's register initialization by Bootloader and Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, u-boot

Can someone clarify when and who does the hardware register initialization?
I am currently working on u-boot in an embedded project and in u-boot i see that many hardware registers are being initialized.
I thought that Bootloader initializes all the hardware registers and the kernel provides drivers to drive the hardware.
But one of the test cases says that "Check that the value of the register set in the kernel is set correctly".
Now I am confused whether Kernel also sets these registers again once the kernel is starting up.
I do not have a clear picture on what happens once the device starts up. Like what is the role of bootloader and what is does when it executing and what kernel does when it starting up.

Thanks.

Comment: U-Boot is often a second-stage (or sometimes even a 3rd-stage) bootloader (i.e. there is an earlier bootloader to load U-Boot into main memory).  Typically each bootloader only initializes the minimal HW subsystems that are required to completes its task, never more. *"the kernel provides drivers to drive the hardware"* -- Writing a statement like that makes me wonder if you really know what a driver is.

Comment: Hi sawdust. thanks for the reply. Your wondering is true. I do not know anything about driver. But I want to learn. That is why i raised this question.

Comment: Platform-specific stuff is going to be done by the BIOS, not the bootloader. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380883/what-is-a-kernel-bootloader/3380910

Comment: The product does not have BIOS. It got U-boot and a linux distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that u-boot initializes only the hardware required to load the kernel and not all the hardware. That was the confusion I had.